# Can I hand off from a node cli app to bash?

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm working on a fairly simple node cli application for my agency that allows you to add clients and any of their sites to a db (lowdb) and then basically run the script with the client name to hand you off to an ssh session on their server. I've tried the `exec` module, but it's just showing the password or key password prompt from ssh and not allowing me to actually continue with the session.

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to basically execute that initial `ssh` command but then just be running that on bash and not through the node app?

For example:
If I use the following code...

```js
exec('ssh [options we always need] client@clientserver.com');
```

I get the following...

```
$ client's password: []
```

But it's just printing the stdout, not allowing me to continue with the session. I just want the node cli to effectively end after starting the bash command running, allowing the user to login and continue as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [dedicated library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh-forward) instead of the command-line interface? Simply, implement the API and get the console input for the 'password', and then just pipe all command-line input to the SSH stream.

With [node-ssh-forward](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh-forward), you simply establish a connection with the server using the input from the CLI and use the `sshConnection.executeCommand('')` command with the input from the user. This library also supports callbacks so you can just console.log the results from the callback.